# Firemonkey embedded ios web browser displays "done" bar issue

Tags: ios, iphone, delphi-xe8

I have an interesting issue with an IOS app, 32bit at present.

I have a simple project with one form, a button and a TWebBrowser component.The "onclick" of the button sets the align property of the twebbrowser to client and opens a webpage (www.trademe.co.nz for testing).

Every thing works ok until I go to use the virtual keyboard (e.g. enter a search). When the virtual keyboard appears I am getting a second "done" button bar appearing above (and behind?) the main one. The main "done" bar includes next and previous buttons, whereas the background one doesn't. It appears that there are two keyboards appearing. I have the issue on both my test phones, one running IOS7 and the other running IOS6 and I believe it is also happening under IOS8.

**Does anyone have any idea what causes this?**

TIA